# SlidingPaneLayout.setShadowResource Android

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I'm developing a APP with a Sliding Pane and works correctly, but I dont know how I can put a shadow like Hangouts Google APP.

It's a bit hard to explain, see this:

[image]

Im trying to use setShadowResource, but I dont know how to design the shadow in nine patch.
Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to create a shadow using a shape with gradient, but dont works :|

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:centerColor="#8B0000"
    android:endColor="#34FFDD"
    android:startColor="#FF00FF" />

</shape>
```

Activity:

```
    mPanes.openPane();
    mPanes.setShadowResource(R.drawable.es_slidingpane_shadow);
    mPanes.setSliderFadeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to set width and height to your drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
    android:centerColor="#8B0000"
    android:endColor="#34FFDD"
    android:startColor="#FF00FF" />
<size android:width="5.0dp" android:height="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```